# メンテナンスのお知らせ：3月2日 (木) 10:00〜11:30 JST

Tags: 討議

[Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387079/314875) に示されているように、日本時間 2023 年 3 月 2 日 (木) 午前 10:00 ( 1:00 UTC / 3 月 1 日 20:00 EST ) からシステムメンテナンスを実施します。サイトは最長で約 90 分読み取り専用モードになります。

ご不便をおかけして申し訳ございませんが何卒ご理解のほどよろしくお願いいたします。